# Get all sub-folders from a specific SharePoint 2013 library using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

How can I get a list of all sub-folders from a specific `SharePoint library` using `CSOM`? I want to provide the same functionality as in SharePoint when the user clicks the 'Choose Folder'.

[image]

I found this article [CAML and the Client Object Model](https://karinebosch.wordpress.com/2012/02/03/caml-and-the-client-object-model/) which I thought was pretty good but I'm getting error when I'm trying the following:

```
using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(this.SpSite))
{
    var web = clientContext.Web;
    var list = web.Lists.GetByTitle('Contracts');

    var query = new CamlQuery();
    query.FolderServerRelativeUrl = "/Contracts";
    query.ViewXml = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>"
    + "<Query>"
    + "   <Where>"
    + "      <Eq><FieldRef Name='FSObjType' /><Value Type='Integer'>1</Value></Eq>"
    + "   </Where>"
    + "</Query>"
    + "</View>";

    var folderItems = list.GetItems(query);
    clientContext.Load(folderItems);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    foreach (ListItem item in folderItems)
    {
        // item[ "..." ];
    }
}
```

I've also tried a different CALM query but to no avail:

```
query.ViewXml = "<View Scope=\"RecursiveAll\"> " +
"<Query>" +
"<Where>" +
"<Eq>" +
"<FieldRef Name=\"FileDirRef\" />" +
"<Value Type=\"Text\">" + title + "</Value>" +
"</Eq>" +
"</Where>" +
"</Query>" +
"</View>";
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

**UPDATE-1:**

I found a question [How to traverse SharePoint Library in Client Object Model?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/41131/how-to-traverse-sharepoint-library-in-client-object-model) asked on `StackExchange` that's very close to what I need but still have a couple of issues with it:

1. It's using recursion which means if you have a lot of levels, it would end up creating numerous requests and could show to be very slow.
2. The data returned is not ordered. Based on the snapshot I've provided, instead of returning 01, 02, 03, etc... it returns the values in a random order.

I was hoping that I would be able to make a single call and get a list of all folders and sub-folders but I guess this could also end up being time consuming.

I guess I've got a couple of choices:

1. Stick the recursion method and figure out how to sort out the data but I still need to figure out the latter.
2. Only request the folders at the top level and only request sub-folder on demand when folder is expanded. Ideally if using this method, it would be nice to know if a folder has any sub-folder which means also having to figure this out.

Getting there but not quite there yet.

So if anyone can provide me with additional feedback, snippets, anything, please do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest the following adjustments for the case of loading all the folders at once:

Since CSOM API already contains [the built in method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.camlquery.createallfoldersquery.aspx) for that matter, loading all the folder items could be performed like this:

```
var folderItems = list.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllFoldersQuery());
```

Secondly, i would suggest to retrieve folder objects from associated list items:

```
var allFolders = folderItems.Select(i => i.Folder).ToList();
```

Example:

```
public static List<Folder> GetAllFolders(List list)
{
    var ctx = list.Context;
    var folderItems = list.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllFoldersQuery());
    ctx.Load(folderItems, icol => icol.Include(i => i.Folder));
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    var allFolders = folderItems.Select(i => i.Folder).ToList();
    return allFolders;
}
```

---

Since the loading of a whole folder structure could be a bottleneck from performance perspective, to avoid that you might consider *load on demand* approach:

Once the form is loaded, retrieve the list of *1st* level folders and populate tree view:

```
var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(libraryTitle);
var folders = FolderManager.GetFolders(list.RootFolder);

var rootNode = new TreeNode(libraryTitle);
folderSelector.Nodes.Add(rootNode);
foreach (var folder in folders)
{
      var folderNode = new TreeNode(folder.Name) {Tag = folder};
      rootNode.Nodes.Add(folderNode);
}
```

and then load the sub folders on demand and populate nodes once the `expand` event is triggered:

```
private void folderTreeView_BeforeExpand(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Node.Level > 0 ) //skip root level
    {
         var folders = FolderManager.GetFolders((Folder)e.Node.Tag);
         foreach (var folder in folders)
         {
                var folderNode = new TreeNode(folder.Name) { Tag = folder };
                e.Node.Nodes.Add(folderNode);
         }
    }
}
```

where

```
public static List<Folder> GetFolders(Folder parentFolder)
{
    var ctx = parentFolder.Context;
    var result = ctx.LoadQuery(parentFolder.Folders.Where(f => !f.ListItemAllFields.ServerObjectIsNull.Value));
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    return result.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post this. I will definitely look at this again later as the load on demand is definitely the way to go as I agree that the method I'm using would potentially create a bottleneck if there are a tonne of folders within a library but I'm only building a prototype for demonstration purpose at this time, so this will do for now.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up figuring it out using the [Caml Designer 2013](http://www.camldesigner.com/). The concept is very good but still quite flaky for my taste which made it unusable but after numerous trial and error, I ended up looking into the section "Query Options".

It turned out that in this section, there is an option to deal with folders & sub-folders and it ended up generating the correct Calm query for me.

This was the final outcome:

```
using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(this.SpSite))
{
    List spList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(title);
    clientContext.Load(spList);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    if (spList != null && spList.ItemCount > 0)
    {
        CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
        camlQuery.ViewXml = 
            "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>"
          + "  <Query>"
          + "    <Where>"
          + "      <Eq><FieldRef Name='FSObjType' /><Value Type='Integer'>1</Value></Eq>"
          + "    </Where>"                            
          + "  </Query>"
          + "  <ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields>"
          + "</View>";

          ListItemCollection listItems = spList.GetItems(camlQuery);

          clientContext.Load(listItems);
          clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

          foreach (var item in listItems)
          {
              Debug.WriteLine($"Title: {item.FieldValues["Title"]} 
              - FileRef: {item.FieldValues["FileRef"]} 
              - FileLeafRef: {item.FieldValues["FileLeafRef"]}");
          }
      }
  }
```

The above code generated the following results:

```
Title: 2016 - FileRef: /Contracts/2016 - FileLeafRef: 2016
Title: 2017 - FileRef: /Contracts/2017 - FileLeafRef: 2017
Title: 01 - FileRef: /Contracts/2016/01 - FileLeafRef: 01
Title: 02 - FileRef: /Contracts/2016/02 - FileLeafRef: 02
Title: 03 - FileRef: /Contracts/2016/03 - FileLeafRef: 03
Title: 04 - FileRef: /Contracts/2016/04 - FileLeafRef: 04
Title: 05 - FileRef: /Contracts/2016/05 - FileLeafRef: 05
Title: 06 - FileRef: /Contracts/2016/06 - FileLeafRef: 06
Title: 07 - FileRef: /Contracts/2016/07 - FileLeafRef: 07
Title: 08 - FileRef: /Contracts/2016/08 - FileLeafRef: 08
Title: 09 - FileRef: /Contracts/2016/09 - FileLeafRef: 09
Title: 10 - FileRef: /Contracts/2016/10 - FileLeafRef: 10
Title: 11 - FileRef: /Contracts/2016/11 - FileLeafRef: 11
Title: 12 - FileRef: /Contracts/2016/12 - FileLeafRef: 12
Title: 01 - FileRef: /Contracts/2017/01 - FileLeafRef: 01
Title: 02 - FileRef: /Contracts/2017/02 - FileLeafRef: 02
Title: 03 - FileRef: /Contracts/2017/03 - FileLeafRef: 03
Title: 04 - FileRef: /Contracts/2017/04 - FileLeafRef: 04
Title: 05 - FileRef: /Contracts/2017/05 - FileLeafRef: 05
Title: 06 - FileRef: /Contracts/2017/06 - FileLeafRef: 06
Title: 07 - FileRef: /Contracts/2017/07 - FileLeafRef: 07
Title: 08 - FileRef: /Contracts/2017/08 - FileLeafRef: 08
Title: 09 - FileRef: /Contracts/2017/09 - FileLeafRef: 09
Title: 10 - FileRef: /Contracts/2017/10 - FileLeafRef: 10
Title: 11 - FileRef: /Contracts/2017/11 - FileLeafRef: 11
Title: 12 - FileRef: /Contracts/2017/12 - FileLeafRef: 12
```

So, all that's left for me to do, look into what other properties are returned in the FieldValues Dictionary and see if there is one that can help me identify a parent or child node but even with what's already there, parsing would easily do the trick.

Hope this helps and saves you some time!

PS: I don't know if any of you SharePoint experts out there have noticed but my original question's code looks very similar to the solution, yet it did not generate the same results. If it's a quick one to highlight, please share as I'd love to know but can't afford to spend any more time on this issue.